# In Chisel test bench, how to write two independent interface processes?

Tags: chisel

Suppose a DUT has two independent interface with different sequential protocols. It should be easy to test each of them in one "process/thread". But the current peekpoketester seems difficult to do this. For example, one push and one pull interfaces:

```
one.valid = 1;
@(posedge clock) begin
if (one.ready)
    one.data <= next
end

two.ready = 1;
@(posedge clock) begin
if (two.valid)
    handle(two.data)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

One way of approaching this is to use the chisel-testers [AdvTester](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-testers/blob/master/src/main/scala/chisel3/iotesters/AdvTester.scala). There is a example using the AdvTester in a manner related to your problem in the [ConcurrentDecoupledTestingSpec](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-testers/blob/master/src/test/scala/examples/ConcurrentDecoupledTestingSpec.scala) which shows how to implement an asynchronous test of a DUT.  Improving the tester eco-system is a current project with Chisel, please contribute specific needs like this as issues at the [chisel3](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel3).